# Data is gone after refresh or closing browser - Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Data is becoming null after i edit and refresh several times the page or after closing and opening the browser the data is gone.

I use db in controller

```
use DB;
```

here is my **view**

```
    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['Admin\SettingsController@index'], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

            <select name="aircraft_id" class="form-control" id="">
              <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true"> Select </option>
              @foreach ($aircrafts as $aircraft)
                  <option name="aircraft_id" value="{{ $aircraft->aircraft_id }}">{{ $aircraft->aircraft_registration_number }}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>

            <br>

            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
            {{Form::submit('BIND', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg', 'name'=>'submit'])}}

                  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

my **controller**

```
 $airid = $request->input('aircraft_id');   <------ used to call textbox

     $aircraft = DB::table('series')   <----------update my data
      ->update(['aircraft_id' => $airid]);
```

So after running and updating all this code , I can manage to update my data but again as ive said after refreshing,closing and reopening or any kind of things that may close or refresh the browser, the data is `NULL` nad `Removed`

What i just want is to make the data permanent

Comment: what data done?

Comment: @AbdurRahman what do you mean sir?

Comment: Are you sure that the data stored successfully? Becoz browser refresh/reload will not change anything on database unless you write code for that.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar yes siir im sure it is stored, i checked it. and my code is all stored in the index index.blade.php is where i update my content and displays it

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar im having the `Confirm Form Resubmission - The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?`

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar be4 i refresh

Comment: @SummerWinter `Confirm Form Resubmission ` doesn't mean your data is stored successfully. The message means, It's asking, you have submitted a form using POST method, Do you want to resubmit again? thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Laravel but looking at it's documentation regarding database updated it looks like you need a `where` statement before the `update`. In some databases when you forget the `where`, all entries in the table will be updated to the passed value.

Also, in HTML, only the `select` element has a `name` attribute. The `option` element should not have a `name`.

Comment: can you give me an answer ? i think you're might right sir good point tho

Comment: i mean the syntax for `where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $airid = $request->input('aircraft_id');   <------ used to call textbox

 $aircraft = DB::table('series')   <----------update my data
  ->update(['aircraft_id' => $airid]);
```

=> it seems like you're trying to updated all 'aircraft_id' to value passed in $airid. This might be wrong when the column definition is Primary_Key or it's defined as unique. So all you need to do is:

```
DB::table('series')
        ->where('aircraft_id', $airid)
        ->update(<column_name> => <value>]);
```

Here  is the column name you would like to update value of.
      is value you would like to set to the desired column you've entered.

Comment: well sir you are right I need to update all column in `aircraft_id`

Comment: `->update(aircraft_id => $airid]);` , sir i need the update query to be like that so that i can update all column, but when i do it is not updating :(

Comment: `$airid` is the select dropdown which has value so i need to have that on my update query

Comment: but when i put 3 on it it is updating but when i put the `$airid` it is not updating

Comment: I believe this is too late reply but I think you need to first debug if you're getting value in $request->input('aircraft_id'); before assigning it to $airid.